I'm trying to implement rounded rectangles that can be used with interpolation, but get weird behavior
    public class RoundRect {
        float width;
        float height;
        float r;
        float fullWidth => width + r * 2;
        float fullHeight => height + r * 2;
        float radWidth => width + r;
        float radHeight => height + r;
        public float perimeter => (radWidth * 2 + radHeight * 2);
        static Exception pointOut = new Exception("Point out of the rectangle");

        public RoundRect(float width, float height, float radius) {
            if (width < radius || height < radius) { throw new Exception("Radius should be less than dimensions"); }
            this.width = width - 2*radius;
            this.height = height - 2*radius;
            r = radius;
        }
        public float CornerByAxisPoint(float p, bool positive) {
            if (Mathf.Abs(p) > r) {
                Debug.Log("Invalid input p: " + p + $".  Must be within [-{r}, {r}]");
                p = Mathf.Clamp(p, -r, r);
            }
            return Mathf.Sqrt(r * r - p * p) * (positive ? 1 : -1);
        }
        public Vector2 GetPointOnBase(float x, bool topSide) {
            if (x <= width) { return new Vector2(x+(topSide ? 0 : -width), (topSide ? r : -r)); }
            else if (x > width) { return new Vector2(x+(topSide ? 0 : -width*2-r), CornerByAxisPoint(x-width+(topSide ? 0 : -r), topSide)); }
            else throw pointOut;
        }
        public Vector2 GetPointOnLegs(float y, bool rightSide) {
            if (y <= height) { return new Vector2(0, y * (rightSide ? -1 : 1)); }
            else if (y > height) { return new Vector2(CornerByAxisPoint(y-height, rightSide)+(rightSide ? -r : r), (rightSide ? -y : y)); }
            else throw pointOut;
        }
        public Vector2 GetPoint(float p) {
            Debug.Log(p);
            if (p <= radWidth) {
                return GetPointOnBase(p, true)+Vector2.right*r; } //cycle top
            else if (p > radWidth && p <= radWidth + radHeight) {
                return GetPointOnLegs(p - radWidth, true)+Vector2.right*fullWidth; } //cycle right
            else if (p > radWidth + radHeight && p <= radWidth*2 + radHeight) {
                return GetPointOnBase(p - (radWidth + radHeight), false)+Vector2.right*radWidth+Vector2.down*height; //cycle bottom
            } else if (p > radWidth*2 + radHeight && p <= radWidth*2 + radHeight*2) {
                return GetPointOnLegs(p - (radWidth*2 + radHeight), false)+Vector2.down*height; //cycle left
            } else throw pointOut;
        }

        public Vector2 InterpolatePoint(float t) => GetPoint(Mathf.Lerp(0f, perimeter, t));

        public static Vector3 OnGround(Vector2 point) {
            return new Vector3(point.x, 0, point.y);
        }
    }

I use GetPointOnLegs to get left-right side positions, GetPointOnBase to get top-bottom side positions. It gives me weird results on corners and Invalid p input at times (comparsion of floating points).
I used epsilon and invalid square root seemingly wasn't a problem anymore but the main issue remained and it's not interpolating nicely on corners, so I returned it back. All the points should be evenly places without weird gaps.
Edit: I figured out the algorithm is irrelavant for mapping points from 0 to perimeter using linear interpolation, because quarter arcs of unit circle are not symmetrical at both ends as absolute difference of y is different, which is reflected on the trigonometrical wave too. What I was doing for arcs is mapping the point reset back to 0 to range unit circle (-1,1) and getting y position using equation of a circle.

At the corners, the spacing would be an "arc segment" (a part of the circumference) equivalent to the spacing that is not  on the corners.

Yes, that's what I meant, but I have a gap there when testing it with instantiating objects with (float i=0;i<10f;i+=0.01) and i/10f as point, and also when doing linear interpolation of points it looks uneven where the gap occurs. https://imgur.com/a/TEKPJfa
I'm using unit circle from -1 to 0 and from 0 to 1 instead of angles and pi so there should be no spacing but looks like there is

To concern debugging, I get sqrt 0.04359015 for p = 0.08999944 (point before the last one) but sqrt 0.0003387309 for p = 0.09999943 (the last point) which probably emerges the gap. Difference in x is equally 0.00999999 between each point

You use the arc segment to calculate the angle of rotation (360 * seg length/circumference). You then rotate the prev point using a RotateTransform. No extra "calcs". You then advance the pivot point from the corner along the border until you hit the next corner and start rotating again.

@GerrySchmitz I figured out a quarter unit circle is not symmetrical as it is reflected on the sin-cos wave too, so I cannot do equal iteration of x to get clean y values anyway, therefore probably using angles can help. Thank you, I may try it.
